# remove complete level of an array

Tags: php

im trying to remove a complete level in an array
all the items starting with [1]

i am having no luck with arrays at all. kinda new to me. and reading all the stuff i find is not clear nor example like mine.

heres my code so far. i can remove the submit. but i cant go any farther plus im not sure how to remove all of them in heading,special,item, etc as item [1] - regular caesar salad

thank you for any help you may provide

```
code
<?php
    // version:
$testarray =    
Array(
        "heading" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Salads',
            "1" => 'Salads',
            "2" => 'Pasta',
        ),

        "special" => Array
        (
            "0" => '',
            "1" => '',
            "2" => '',
        ),

        "item" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Small Green',
            "1" => 'Regular Caesar',
            "2" => 'Baked Lasagna',
        ),

        "description" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Grape tomatoes, onions, green peppers and cucumbers on the bed of crisp lettuce.',
            "1" => 'Classic recipe with romaine lettuce and croutons',
            "2" => 'With meat sauce, tomato vegetarian sauce or Alfredo sauce',
        ),

        "price" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'See Desc',
            "1" => '$5.99',
            "2" => '$9.69',
        ),

        "notes" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Available in Small ($2.99), Regular ($5.99)',
            "1" => '',
            "2" => '',
        ),

        "submit_val" => 'Submit'
    );


echo "testarray";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($testarray);
echo "</pre>";  
echo "<hr>";

$removed_data=removeItem($testarray,'Submit');

echo "removed_data";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($removed_data);
echo "</pre>";  

echo "<hr>";
die();

// works for submit
function removeItem($look_in_Array, $remove){
    foreach($look_in_Array as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br>'; 
    if ($value ==$remove) {
            echo 'found '.$remove."<br>";
            unset($look_in_Array[$key]);
    }
    }
     return $look_in_Array;
}
?>
```

output desired?:

```
sample of desired output
$testarray =    
Array(
        "heading" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Salads',
            "1" => 'Pasta',
        ),

        "special" => Array
        (
            "0" => '',
            "1" => '',
        ),

        "item" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Small Green',
            "1" => 'Baked Lasagna',
        ),

        "description" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Grape tomatoes, onions, green peppers and cucumbers on the bed of crisp lettuce.',
            "1" => 'With meat sauce, tomato vegetarian sauce or Alfredo sauce',
        ),

        "price" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'See Desc',
            "1" => '$9.69',
        ),

        "notes" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Available in Small ($2.99), Regular ($5.99)',
            "1" => '',
        ),

        "submit_val" => 'Submit'
    );
```

Comment: What kind of end result are you looking for?

Comment: Like @devlshone asked, could you provide an example of what your result array should look like (based on your example array in your question, perhaps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to remove any array key [1]. If you're doing this as a function anyway, you can either use unset or declare and return a new array. Using unset() might be what you're looking for, but it is sort of a waste of time in a function because it only passes a local variable. Instead, you may want to pass values onto a new array. Please note that this will retain key values.

```
function removeItemsRecursive($array,$searchKey) {
 /*
 ** Finds any key value that equals $searchKey
 ** in a multi-level array and does not pass anything
 ** equal to $searchKey.
 */
     foreach($array AS $key=>$value) {  //go through each array and assign [key] => value to $key and $value, respectively
        if($key !== $searchKey) //if a key is not equal to the $searchKey (aka 1 for example) then assign something to $newArray
        { 
            if(is_array($value)) //if the value inside of the array is another array (for multilevel arrays)
            {
                $newArray[$key] = removeItemsRecursive($value,$searchKey);  //loop through the function and do this for the next level down.
            }
            else //if the value inside of the array is scalar
            {
                $newArray[] = $array[$key]; //the new array is assigned the current value where the array key is not equal to $searchKey.
            }
        }

     }
     return $newArray;
}
```

This will essentially go through each value of the $array and pass that value to $newArray if the $key is not $searchKey, aka removeItemsRecursive($array,1); will return a new array without any values with the key being 1.

**Calling the Function**

To call the function, simply add:

```
$array = removeItemsRecursive($testarray,1);
```

When looking at this new array, you will see the results you're looking for.

```
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($array);
echo "</PRE>";
//returns the array you're looking for.
```

Comment: does this do only level one like submit - that i can do with my code im looking for a way to do the (added) desired output. i ask because you mentioned it does not do multi level to pass a value, if i understood this right

Comment: No, this is recursive. Notice the call to the function within the function. That loops through until there is nothing else for the function to parse. Recursive functions are a vital thing to know about if you are looking to parse multi-level arrays,especially if you do not know how deep that array might go or to simplify code.

Comment: Edited to reflect how to call it.

Comment: works great but it wont remove [0] item[0] small green salad removes all the others just great. thanks for the comments too that helps a lot

Comment: Right you are! if($key != $searchKey) should actually be if($key !== $searchKey). That means it is not strictly equal to. PHP loosely checking this will read 0 as false. We want to check the value strictly. If you re-copy it will work.

Comment: works now thank you this is what i was looking for accepting as solution

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeLevel($a, $l) {      // $a = entire array, $l = level to remove
    $removed = array();
    foreach ($a as $inner) {        // iterate through the outer array
        array_splice($inner,$l,1);  // remove the "$l"th element of the $inner array
    }
    return $a;                      // return new array with level removed
}
```

`$arrBetter = removeLevel($testarray, 2)` will return the array with that level of data removed!

Comment: OH i like this one i can understand it...im going to test this one

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in - line of  -   $removed = [];

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in - unset($inner[$l]);        // remove

Comment: Just comment out that line. It doesn't change the original array, anyway.

Comment: k works now but i need the array with the removed item taken out returned not the items its taking out.

Comment: i don't have enough points for answer is useful or i would on this one i like its simplicity and i understand it better - sorry

Comment: There you go... use it with the recent edits and you'll be all set!

Comment: really does not like unset wow - Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets -       unset($a[$k][$l]);        // remove *** what happened to array push?

Comment: `array_push` is no longer needed. Try it now with the `array_splice` function.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

use unset function in php. in your case you  could just iterate over the array and remove all the element at position 1.